# Stop a firebase function from retrying on timeout?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to stop a Firebase Cloud Function from retrying if it times out?

It looks like it is possible to [config the retry logic of Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries). But I can't find that setting anywhere when using Firebase functions.

The functions that are doing this are triggered with:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    ...
});
```

The function is sending a POST request to an outside service that has a tendency to hang, even when the operation was successful.

When this happens I see logs for the function execution starting, then timing out, then immediately starting again. What is causing this retry? And can I stop it from retrying?

Comment: What *exactly* do the logs say?  Are you observing that the work of the function is actually done twice, or are you just observing the logs?

Comment: The logs just say: `Function execution took 540001 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'`. Then the next log is `Function execution started`. And yes, the function sends messages and people are getting duplicate messages.

Answer (score 2):

This is about [HTTP Protocol](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.4). Also retry configuration is not applicable for Http triggered cloud functions.

When a cloud function terminates due to timeout, it basically returns a 408: Request Time-out response. If your browser support 408 HTTP Protocol, it will resend the request to cloud function. I am not sure but Chrome does this while Safari doesn't.

I am also suffering from this strange behavior of Firebase functions(sending 408 on timeout). I think only way to fix this is to create a wrapper on your function which returns a response just before function times out. I am trying to create one but couldn't have done it yet.

Comment: I wonder if I can resolve the promise before the cloud function timeout occurs. I'll try this someday if I really need to fix my similar issue. In this case, I'll add a timeout of my own, faster than the cloud timeout. Then I would resolve the promise - end the function - before the cloud function overall time out occurs. Of course this might not be applicable to other scenarios, and I apologize in advance for my restricted suggestion. And I can't guarantee - yet - that this will solve the problem. Did not try yet. Hope I could help a tiny bit, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Retries are off by default.

You can configure your function in the [Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list).

Comment: I've got a firebase function that's retrying, and I can't find the setting in the cloud console. Where is that setting? And if it's not the cloud function retrying on timeout, what could be triggering the retry?

Comment: You're going to have to edit your question to be a lot more specific about what you're doing to trigger the function, what you're observing, and how your observations are different from what you're expecting.

Comment: Hi Doug, I've updated the question with the little information I have. The gcloud functions docs mention "retry on failure" checkbox in the settings. The question is really just: does that setting exist for firebase functions? And if it does, where is it? Thanks!

Comment: My reading of the documentation is the same: that this is off by default. Yet, I have certainly seen functions retry, looking in the logs. It is unclear under what conditions this happens...  but it definitely can happen even if the setting is off. (Also wanted: a way to turn the setting on programmatically.)

Comment: @KyleCordes
 If you see what looks like a retry in the console log, refresh the page and see if it's just a bug in the console that duplicates log items occasionally.

Comment: @DougStevenson Oh yes, I have seen the duplicated log entry item also. I think when that happens the duplicates have the same timestamp. But I've also seen cases where the function runs a first time, fails in some unusual way, then runs again. And this is for a function which is definitely not have the retry setting enabled. So far we have been working around this unexpected behavior by redoubling efforts to make functions idempotent -  generally a good idea for cloud functions anyway.